# Compile and run java classes in different packages with multiple jar libraries

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I have a project including two packages and several classes in each.

There are also two jar libraries (json-simple-1.1.1.jar and guava-10.0.1.jar) included through the "Project Properties --> Build path" window.

I can run the project in Eclipse, but I want to compile and run them on the server (using command line).

So I moved the whole project folder (Let me say Proj1) to the server.

I want to compile these classes on the server. Then, run one of those classes (let me say Class1.java).

I have tried the following command to compile all java files in all folders:

```
javac -classpath ./guava-10.0.1.jar;./json_simple-1.1.1.jar -sourcepath src -d src ./src/**/*.java
```

But got error:

```
javac: no source files 
Usage: javac <options> <source files> 
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: ./json_simple-1.1.1.jar: No such file or directory
```

When I remove the second jar file from the command, I get a lot of errors from the lines of the classes that are working with json (meaning that it knows my source files!).

Please guide me how to compile them in command line and run Class1.java.

Comment: Shouldn't the `;` be `:`

Comment: @Rajeev:
Then I get 18 errors!
Starting with: 
./src/bugTriaging/JSONtoTSV.java:9: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
-------------------
And errors in the lines using json, etc.

Comment: Do a `pwd`. And if the directory is fine, try your command as `javac -cp .:guava-10.0.1.jar:json_simple-1.1.1.jar -sourcepath src -d src ./src/**/*.java`

Comment: @Rajeev: Again the same error.
I am in the project folder (Proj1) and the two jar files are also copied there.

Comment: Note that the classes are in ./src/package1 or ./src/package2 folders.

Comment: During compile, the classpath is also searched for source files. Can you put all jars into a `lib` folder, create a `bin` folder and try running command as `javac -cp lib/guava-10.0.1.jar:lib/json_simple-1.1.1.jar -sourcepath src -d bin ./src/**/*.java`

Comment: @Rajeev:No difference. The same errors.